# Move a UserControl from a ContentControl to another one programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-tree

In a WPF app I want to move a UserControl from a ContentControl to another one in code:

```
 myContentControl2.Content = myUserControl;
```

in this case I get an error:
*Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.*

In a [ControlControl class description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) I can see a [RemoveVisualChild method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.removevisualchild.aspx), but when I try to use it in code I get an **Unknown method** error

```
myContentControl1.RemoveVisualChild(myUserControl);//here I get an "Unknown method" error
```

Where am I wrong?
**How to move a UserControl from a ContentControl to another one in code-behind?**

Comment: @Maheep: yes, with what i answered.

Comment: @Clemens: Yep. What I have updated is same as your answer. But I tried the solution independently and updated. I am Ok with your answer as accepted one. But happy about I too learned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

```
myContentControl1.Content = null;
```

to remove myUserControl from myContentControl1 before setting

```
myContentControl2.Content = myUserControl;
```

By the way, don't confuse the logical tree with the visual tree. Get more information in [Trees in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx) in the MSDN.

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you! And your note about trees is helpful as well, +1

Answer (score 1):

> In a ControlControl class description I can see a RemoveVisualChild method, but when I try to use it in code I get an Unknown method error

This is because `RemoveVisualChild` and RemoveLogicalChild are protected methods which you can not access in your class directly. If you want to use this method then create a derived class from `ContentControl` and expose these methods using some public method wrapper in that class.

Better option is to remove `myUserControl` from logical tree of `myContentControl1` before adding it some other control's logical tree. To achieve this you can set the `Content` property of `myContentControl1` to something else or to `null`.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear about using protected methods, +1