# Fast method of changing a parent of a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

In a WPF app I can move a `UserControl` from a `ContentControl` to another one in code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9062335/308012):

```
myContentControl1.Content = null;
myContentControl2.Content = myUserControl;
```

The problem is that the `UserControl` that has been moved is a rather heavy one (consists of a lot of smaller controls). So the above operation takes a significant amount of time, almost as long as when I load the `UserControl` initially. It seems that every element in that `UserControl` goes through processing to be moved under another `ContentControl`.

Is there a more efficient and **faster method** of **placing a `UserControl` under another parent** (in my case a `ContentControl`) as its child (without the need for UI thread to process all its elements every time)? (Dynamically, in code-behind)

Comment: Please, give a reason for downvoting

Comment: That's hard to answer without knowlegde about why you would do that. One thing of course is clear: changing the (logical) parent of the control will result in re-building its visual tree, including all the potentially expensive layout calculations. So why do you need to re-parent at all? Oh, i didn't downvote...

Comment: @Clemens What I'm trying to achieve is to cash my UserControl somewhere in a non-visible part of UI, in order to make the visualizing my UserControls faster (I need constantly change them back and forth)

Comment: Couldn't you simply move it out of the visible area by a TranslateTransform, by setting the control's RenderTransform property, or even simpler, set the control invisible? What about working with two controls like you do and while showing one, updating the other, invisible one in the background and then toggle both their visibility.

Comment: Toggle their visibility between Visible and Hidden, not Collapsed since that would result in another layout cycle.

Comment: Toggling the control Visible/Hidden is a perfectly fast process. The problem is that while I make a UserControl hidden I need to set the container (ContentControl) empty for another UserControl to be loaded in. I should operate with only one container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of switching a `ContentControl`'s content between your two `UserControl`'s, put both `UserControl`'s in a `Grid` and toggle their `Visibility`. While showing one with current data, update the other, invisible one in the background. When updating is done, toggle both control's visibility from `Visible` to `Hidden` and vice versa. Don't use `Collapsed`, since that would force a new layout cycle.

Putting both in a `Grid` without specifying `Row` or `Column` makes them lie above each other.

Comment: This is maybe the only way to go, if, as you have said in your comments, "changing the (logical) parent of the control will result in re-building its visual tree, including all the potentially expensive layout calculations". In fact, what I whanted to make clear for myself by asking this question is exactly: "is it possible to avoid re-building the visual tree?". If it's not possible, then I should perhaps try the way you suggested. (Though it's the way I was trying to avoid by looking for a way to move my Control under another parent.) Thanks! +1